# Error en subir archivos a heroku

Tags: heroku

ayer subi mi backend a heroku el cual tiene un api de subir imagenes, localmente esto funciona bien, esta conectado a una base de datos mongodb en la nube, me arroja un error de POST url 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR, he visto todo y esta correcto, no se si tenga algo que ver heroku, que recomendacion me darian? Alguien ha hecho un proyecto con Nodejs que haya desplegado en heroku y suba imagenes y las muestre ??

[Repositorio github de las api](https://github.com/Emocrat3/api-proyectos-)

Comment: utilizas heroku la versión gratuita?

Comment: Hola, si utilizo la versión gratis

Comment: En la version gratuita no es posible subir o cargar archivos, lo unico que puedes hacer es subir todos los archivos o imagenes que tu pagina necesite pero no puedes interacturar  subiendo archivos en tiempo real, esto es porque es una cuenta gratuita.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu explicación!!

Answer (score 0):

Heroku utiliza lo que se llama un sistema de archivos efímero . Esto significa que solo se puede acceder a su sistema de archivos local a un único dinamómetro, y una vez que el dinamómetro se detiene, reinicia o mueve, todos los archivos del sistema de archivos local se destruyen.

La única forma para que su proceso de Trabajo demorado transfiera archivos a un proceso externo sería almacenar los archivos en una ubicación más permanente. Esto podría ser S3, una base de datos, archivos de Rackspace, etc., pero para Heroku no puede ser el sistema de archivos local.